# what is the correct syntax for select statement with date and string condition?

Tags: c#

this is my code

```
    class CLSAttend
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer op = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    public DataTable loadhooodor(string heUsers)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DataTable loadhooodor = new DataTable();
        string procedure = "select * from HoodoorEnseraf where heDate= @today and  heUsers= @heUsers";
        OleDbParameter[] param = new OleDbParameter[2];
        param[0] = new OleDbParameter("@today", OleDbType.Date);
        param[0].Value = today;
        param[1] = new OleDbParameter("@heUsers", OleDbType.VarChar);
        param[1].Value = heUsers;
        loadhooodor=op.selectData(procedure, param);
        return loadhooodor;
    }

}
```

and attend form

```
            dataGridView1.DataSource = attend.loadhooodor(heUser.Text);
```

but still didn't get any data from the table to my datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call
`dataGridView1.DataBind();`